# Characterize the family of all $n\times n$ nonsingular matrices $A$ for which one step of the Gauss-Seidel algorithm solves $Ax=b$, starting at

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

**Characterize the family of all $n\times n$ nonsingular matrices $A$ for which one step of the Gauss-Seidel algorithm solves $Ax=b$, starting at the vector $x=0$**

I know that if $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant, then the Gauss-seidel method converges for any starting vector $x^{(0)}$. How can I use this to find how $A$ should be? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If $A = L + U$, and our initial vector is $0$, what is the next approximation of a solution that Gauss-Seidel computes?

That next approximation must be $b$ (that's what "one step ... solves" means). So, what does that tell you about $L$, $U$ and $A$?

You need to at least try these before someone here is going to give you anything like an answer.

Comment: I have that $x^{(k+1)}=(I-Q^{-1}A)x^{(k)}+Q^{-1}b$ where $Q=$triangular lower of $A$ by definition, with which $x^{(1)}=Q^{-1}b$ and so $b=Ax^{(1)}=AQ^{-1}b$. So $A$ must meet this last equation, when does it comply? ($A^{-1}b=Q^{-1}b$ so $A^{-1}=Q^{-1}$ so $A=Q$)?